# Is there any way i can pass in only the values of a list to a dictionary and not the reference of the list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, reference

Is there any way i can pass in only the values of a list to a dictionary and not the reference of the list?

```
*my_list = [1, 2, 3]
my_dict = {"list": my_list}
print(my_dict["list"])
my_list.pop()
print(my_dict["list"])*
```

currently the output is:
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2]

i want it to be:
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]

Comment: you can use * to unpack the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a new list with your original list's values in the dictionary so that it won't be mutated when you pop from my_list.

```
my_dict = {"list": [item for item in my_list]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a copy of the list before adding it to the dict:

```python
my_dict = {'list': list(my_list)}
```

What's happening is that `my_dict['list']` is referring to the same value as `my_list` rather than a copy of it, i.e. sharing the data. Since `.pop()` destructively modifies the list, the element is lost in the variable as well.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612815/10973209 for an overview of ways to copy a list and https://stackoverflow.com/a/430958/10973209 for an explanation of pass-by-reference vs pass-by-value in general.